# MongoDB differences between NumberLong and simple Integer?

Tags: mongodb

What are the main differences (size, speed, etc) between the datatypes double, NumberLong, NumberInt or a simple Integer in MongoDB?

If I want to save a small fixed number (something between 0 and 1000) which data type should I use?

Comment: The native int is 32bit while numberlong allows 64bit, a small int you can use just the native representation of integer

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**NumberInt**

By default, the mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values. The mongo shell provides the `NumberInt()` constructor to explicitly specify 32-bit integers.

**NumberLong**

By default, the mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values. The mongo shell provides the `NumberLong()` class to handle 64-bit integers.

The `NumberLong()` constructor accepts the long as a string:

```
NumberLong("2090845886852")
```

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/

Comment: The shell and MongoDB itself are two different things, the shell treats ints as float becaue of a javascript limitation but MongoDB will treat them as int and since no language here is specified you cannot rely on the int as float treatment occuring for the op

Comment: I just ran into a problem - this doesn't work when editing a field. If editing, you need to delete the field first and then save it as the desired type, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894019/how-do-i-save-a-mongo-field-value-as-long/36894239#36894239

Answer (score 26):

`NumberLong` and `NumberInt` are not data types in MongoDB but JavaScript functions in the MongoDB shell.

Data types in MongoDB are defined in the BSON specification: http://bsonspec.org/spec.html

Numbers are stored as type 0x01 (floating point), type 0x10 (32-bit integer) or type 0x12 (64-bit integer).

If you insert or update a document in the MongoDB shell, then `NumberLong` creates a 64-bit integer, `NumberInt` creates a 32-bit integer, and a regular JavaScript number creates a floating-point value. This is because there are no integers in JavaScript, only floating-point numbers.

Output in the MongoDB shell shows floating-point numbers and 32-bit integers as JavaScript numbers, whereas 64-bit integers are shown as calls to `NumberLong`:

```
> db.inttest.insert({f: 1234, i: NumberInt("1234"), l: NumberLong("1234")})
> db.inttest.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5396fc0db8e0b3e2dedb59b0"),
        "f" : 1234,
        "i" : 1234,
        "l" : NumberLong(1234)
}
```

Different MongoDB drivers provide different methods of inserting different types of numbers. For example, the C++ driver creates a 64-bit integer if you append a `long long` value to a BSONObjectBuilder.

Queries match whenever the numbers are equal. In the above example, the queries

```
> db.inttest.find({i:1234})
> db.inttest.find({l:1234})
> db.inttest.find({f:1234})
> db.inttest.find({i:NumberLong("1234")})
> db.inttest.find({l:NumberLong("1234")})
> db.inttest.find({f:NumberLong("1234")})
```

all match the inserted document.