# How to work with NumberLong() with nodejs mongo driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to insert data into my mongoDB, like such:

```
db.collection('Test').insert({
     "Name" : "Some",
     "UserID" : NumberLong(2147483647),
      ...
```

Inserts should happen from a nodejs script that interacts with mongo db
All is well, except for the NumberLong().

I'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: NumberLong is not defined
    at /root/MongoPolluter/MongoPolluter.js:107:23
    at connectCallback (/root/MongoPolluter/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:505:5)
    at /root/MongoPolluter/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:443:13
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

**What I have tried:**

- adding `var BSON = require('bson');` after installing it. Maybe I should use BSONElements?
- Read this: [MongoDB differences between NumberLong and simple Integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185220/mongodb-differences-between-numberlong-and-simple-integer) - from which I go the notion that I could use the NumberLong only from mongo shell? Not sure if that is correct.
- Also read about this: `var Long = require('mongodb').Long;` - should I just replace NumbreLong() w/ Long.fromString('')? Is there no way of getting the NumberLong() to work?

Thanks

Comment: `Long.fromString('')` solution worked. But would be interesting to see ifs possible to use `NumberLong()` still. Same problem with `ISOdate()` (need to use `new Date()`).

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Long.html

Answer (score 1):

NumberLong is using for mongo shell only. If you use in nodejs (javascript) it no mean.
I use mongoose and only Number type of data

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var MyNumber = mongoose.model('my_number', { long_number: Number });

var record = new MyNumber({ long_number: 1234556 });
record.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('ok');
  }
});

// have to defind ObjectId when use even it a default type data of mongodb
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003');
```