# mongo.Long $inc fails for large number

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using the `mongodb 2.2.33` library under nodejs (x64) and am having trouble incrementing a field:

```
  it('increment-test', function () {
    let db = repository.db;
    return setup
      .then(() => {
        return db.collection('product').save({ name: 'product1', amount: 0 });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return db.collection('product').update({}, 
                   { $inc: { "amount": mongo.Long(5000000000000000) } });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return db.collection('product').find({}).toArray();
      })
      .then((results) => {
        assert.equal(results[0].amount, 5000000000000000);//fails
      })

  });
```

This test fails; instead of `5000000000000000` you actually get `937459712`

How can i get this to work under NodeJS? `mongo.Long` appears to be the correct type to use from NodeJS but doesnt work.
In case you were wondering the above test *passes* when you use another number bigger than `Int32` - e.g. `3147483647`
The largest number this passes with is `4294967296` which is `2^32 -1`

Comment: That's JavaScript mate. Which is why the `Long` accepts a "string" as an argument. `NumberLong("5000000000000000")`. Or just type in `NumberLong("5000000000000000") / 2` to be more succinct. People thought about this long before you came across it.

Comment: @NeilLunn why do you refer to`NumberLong` when the issue refers to `mongo.Long` ? nb, `mongo.Long("5000000000000000")` also does not fix problem

Comment: There's a [`fromString()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Long.html#.fromString), I actually near linked that in the original comment but "your question" shows `NumberLong()` as it is viewed from the shell. But it's the same implementation in ALL drivers, and it's pretty well documented as well.

Comment: Related: [MongoDB differences between NumberLong and simple Integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185220/mongodb-differences-between-numberlong-and-simple-integer)

Comment: @NeilLunn can you please explain what is wrong with "my question"

Comment: What do you mean "what's wrong"? You used `Long(5000000000000000)` and you are meant to use `Long.fromString("5000000000000000")` or `high` and `low` in the constructor, whatever "floats your boat". It is actually [there in the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Long.html). All I see is that you are asking something that indicates you did not look at the documentation. So I'm showing you where the documentation is. Somehow I have this strange view that this allows you to continue and resolve the issue.

Comment: @NeilLunn please add as an answer if you wish